# Parsing json form data for submission to API

Tags: javascript, json

I need to submit form data as JSON to an API. Here's a snippet of my serialized form data:

```
{
    "Type":["foo", "bar", "blah"],
}
```

The API requires that the data be submitted in the following format:

```
{
    "Type":"foo,bar,blah",
}
```

I'm looking for a parser based approach to converting this data rather than resorting to `replace/regex`. Any advice is welcome.

I'm using this function to serialize the form data:

```
(function ($) {
        $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {

            var o = {};
            var a = this.serializeArray();
            $.each(a, function () {
                if (o[this.name]) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
            return o;
        };
    })(jQuery)
```

The data is then posted to the API like so:

```
$("#contactForm").submit( function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = $(this).serializeFormJSON();

        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "the submit URL",
            "method": "POST",
            "headers": {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            },
            "processData": false,
            "data": JSON.stringify(formData),
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
```

Comment: How are you creating the form data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through your object checking if the value is array then join the element using `.join(',')` and replace them in the object like :

```js
var obj = {
  "Type1": ["foo", "bar", "blah"],
  "Type2": ["foo", "blah"],
  "Type3": ["bar", "blah"],
};

for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      obj[key] = obj[key].join(',');
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could just join the array with `array.join(',')`

Answer (score 0):

Just use JavaScript `toString()`. Simple and easy.

Single Key:

```
var obj = {
    "Type": ["foo", "bar", "blah"]
};

obj['Type'] = obj['Type'].toString();
// obj = {Type: "foo,bar,blah"}
```

Multiple Key:

```
var obj = {
    "Type1": ["foo", "bar", "blah"],
    "Type2": ["foo", "blah"],
    "Type3": ["bar", "blah"]
};

for(k in obj) obj[k] = obj[k].toString();
// obj = { Type1: "foo,bar,blah", Type2: "foo,blah", Type3: "bar,blah" }
```

This works wonderful if all parameters needs to be string, except is not everything needs to be string:

```
var obj = {
  "Type1": ["foo", "bar", "blah"],
  "Type2": 888888888,
  "Type3": "foo",
  "Type4": "342333",
  "Type5": ["bar"]
};

for(k in obj) obj[k] = obj[k].toString();
// obj =  { Type1: "foo,bar,blah", Type2: "888888888", Type3: "foo", Type4: "342333", Type5: "bar" }
```